# How to easily see a list of stylesheets in the order they are loaded in Google Chrome

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I'm confused by a somewhat simple thing, determining the loading order of CSS stylesheets in Google Chrome.

I would have thought by simply going to `Dev Tools -> Network tab -> filter for Stylesheets` would show the order that the browser loaded in the stylesheets (and thus correct cascade). However when I reload multiple times the order shown in Dev Tools changes seemingly randomly. It doesn't matter whether I select `Timeline`, `Start Time` or `End Time` I can't seem to replicate the order as determined by the HTML.

What am I missing?

Comment: another this you can do is go to the elements tab of the dev tools and look inside the head section... the order of link tags should give you the order it was loaded

Comment: I didn't want to have to comb through the entire source code, I just wanted a simple list.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stylesheet files themselves can be *loaded* in any order (they are usually loaded in parallel anyway) but they will be *processed* in the correct order, so as you have seen, you cannot rely on the Network tab.

You should be able to check [`document.styleSheets`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.styleSheets) tho. Try putting this in the console. It will return some nulls for inline stylesheets, but should get the imported files in the correct order:

```
;(function() { for(var i = 0; i < document.styleSheets.length; i++){ console.log(document.styleSheets[i].href); } })()
```

Comment: isnt loading and processing the same? sorry if this is dumb question

Comment: No not necessarily, it will get all the bits together and then run through them (sorry for the poor response, in a hurry)

Comment: Using this script does indeed retrieve the order properly. I just would have thought Chrome Dev Tools would have made this much easier to determine.

Comment: It seems I have to infuse Dev Tools with this functionality (in order to remember for later) by saving the script as a custom `Snippet` under the `Sources` tab. :|